# Does Agora.io RTM provides on typing status?

Tags: agora.io

I have developed a chat application using the Agora RTM API and I want to show the "on typing" animation in my application when a user starts typing anything.

So far, I've looked everywhere but I couldn't find any single link or doc referencing to an article that states that agora provides the "on typing" event.

- Does agora provides it? Or maybe some method is available which lets you send custom events?
- If not then can we do it some other way (For instance, socket.io) and even if we do that way, would that be efficient?
- Or should we re-develop our chat system using socket?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Agora RTM SDK does not have the related api. However, there is a work around: When a user A starts typing, you can send a signal through RTM to other users B & C who he is chatting with. On B & C end, when they receive that signal, they can display "A is typing" animation. Similarly, when user A stops typing, you can send another signal to notify B & C.

Comment: can you please provide any reference to doc or article on how to send/receive signal through RTM?

Comment: You can find the doc here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android

Comment: aah! never mind, I talked to the support team and they said no that they don't support such feature till

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RyanLarge13/Personal_Portfolio

This is a link to a profile project I have been creating on github where I implement agoraRTM sdk. Viewcode/Javascript/agoraRTM.js you will find code that implements a typing animation. It took me a while to figure it out, but it works well. It might not be the best for production purposes, but for small applications it could do the trick. Look for a showTyping() function. And everywhere I might call it to understand how it is all working.

Basically what I did was listen for the key down even on my form and call sendMessage() every time unless event.key = 'Enter' this sets up a signal defined as undefined to be sent each time a key is pressed and the showTyping() function handles weather or not your animation needs to be displayed. I am sure there are many better ways to write it, but I have yet to find someone who has done it in this scenario. Good luck!! I hope my code is of some type of help.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.